# How to test whether my android application is receiving data or not?

Tags: java, php, android, apache, import

I am currently developing an android application and I'm running into a few errors. I can't figure out what the problem is, so I used a simple source code from the web which doesn't use the functions which I have a problem with.
First, when try to run that I get the error "localhost access denied". I figured out how to solve that problem. Now my problem is that the application is not getting the data from my PHP code (I am sure about it) and I am not sure whether it's sending data or not.
This is a login application, so two way communication is needed. I tried to echo a particular value from the PHP and set the android to display a particular message for that value and lastly I put the message "nothing received" (using the **IF Condition**). I am only getting the "nothing received" message.

Can anyone help me with this?

**check.php**

```
<?php 
 //$un="admin";  
//$pw="admin"; 
$un=$_POST['username'];  
$pw=$_POST['password'];  
//connect to the db  
$user = "root";  
$pswd = "";  
$db = "bcasdb";  
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', $user, $pswd);  
mysql_select_db($db, $conn);  
//run the query to search for the username and password the match  
$query = "SELECT * FROM `bcasdb`.`tbl_user_login` WHERE u_username= '$un' AND u_password ='$pw'" ;  
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to verify user because : " . mysql_error());  

//this is where the actual verification happens  
//if(mysql_num_rows($result) >1)  
// ( $un == “ajay” && $pw == “ajay”)  
echo 1;  // for correct login response  
//else  
//echo 0; // for incorrect login response  
//
?>
```

**Login.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class login2 extends Activity {
    EditText un,pw;
    TextView error;
    Button ok;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      /*  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            System.out.println("*** My thread is now configured to allow connection");
        }*/
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        un=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_un);
        pw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_pw);
        ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        error=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_error);

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", un.getText().toString()));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pw.getText().toString()));
                //String valid = "1";
                String response = null;
                try {
                    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/login/check.php", postParameters);
                    String res=response.toString();
                   // res = res.trim();
                   // res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");                            
                    //error.setText(res);

                   if(res.equals("1"))
                        error.setText("Correct Username or Password");
                    else if(res=="1"){
                        error.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password"); }
                    else{
                        error.setText("Nothing Received");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    un.setText(e.toString());
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**CustomHttpClient.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParams;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

public class CustomHttpClient {
    /** The time it takes for our client to timeout */
    public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds

    /** Single instance of our HttpClient */
    private static HttpClient mHttpClient;

    /**
     * Get our single instance of our HttpClient object.
     *
     * @return an HttpClient object with connection parameters set
     */
    private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
        if (mHttpClient == null) {
            mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
            ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        }
        return mHttpClient;
    }

    /**
     * Performs an HTTP Post request to the specified url with the
     * specified parameters.
     *
     * @param url The web address to post the request to
     * @param postParameters The parameters to send via the request
     * @return The result of the request
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static String executeHttpPost(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
            UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
            request.setEntity(formEntity);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();

            String result = sb.toString();
            return result;
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Performs an HTTP GET request to the specified url.
     *
     * @param url The web address to post the request to
     * @return The result of the request
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(url));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();

            String result = sb.toString();
            return result;
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Try commenting out `setSoTimeout()` until you're sure the code is bug free. It is probably not the root of the problem, however it has caused me headaches before, and hopefully will help the debugging process.

Comment: no, still i receiving the same message

Comment: before your whole `if(res.equals("1"))
                        error.setText("Corre....`, could you just do `error.setText(res)` and see if anything shows up? (*in your `Login.java`*)

Comment: i am getting a form code in HTML

Comment: i using the WAMP server, its giving me warning, do u know how to to stop that

Answer (score 0):

Check by this code if you get the response then u check it in your code if not then your service didn't hit. 
try{

```
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpPost request = new HttpPost();
       URI website = new URI("Your Url");
       request.setURI(website);
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
       in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
               response.getEntity().getContent()));
       String line = in.readLine();
       Log.d("response from website.... ",line)
   }catch(Exception e){
       Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
   }
```